# Prisma - When use include return only subobject fields

Tags: typescript, prisma

I wrote this function that filter the table `building` end optionally I can pass a `Prisma.BuildingInclude` object to return one ore more subobject.

```
async describeEntity(filter: Filter, include?: Prisma.BuildingInclude): Promise<CCResponse> {
  try {
    const entity = await this.prisma.building.findMany({
      where: this.queryCondition(filter),
      include,
    });

    return new CCResponse('OK', entity);
  }
  catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return new CCResponse('INTERNAL_ERROR', this.content['GeneralError']);
  }
}
```

The problem is that if I pass the `include` parameter, into prisma response I have also the fields of the `building`. How can I return only the subobject fields when the `include` parameter is present?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace the `include` condition with a `select` condition to solve this.

For example, to find many `building` records with the exact same `where` condition, but to only return the desired relation sub-object fields, a query might look like this

```js
 const entity = await this.prisma.building.findMany({
      where: this.queryCondition(filter),
      select: {
            relationSubObjectOne: true,  //change relationSubObjectOne to appropriate relation name..
            relationSubObjectTwo: true,  //change relationSubObjectTwo to appropriate relation name..
            // ... other fields/subobjects you might be interested in.
        },
    });
```

You can learn more about this in the **Include relations and select relation fields** subsection of the [Select fields](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/select-fields#include-relations-and-select-relation-fields) article in the Prisma Docs.